# Mirroring folders

Tags: mac

I want to know if there is a way to have mirror folders with a remote machine. I see some solutions for syncing folders with a backup drive, but I am not interested in that. I want to sync a folder with a remote machine through ssh. I am on OSX leopard

Ted.

Comment: Is SSH a requirement?

Comment: also for clarity, you want both to have live access concurrently or you want to mirror it on a regular basis?

Comment: Hmmm live access concurrently, don't know what you mean by that? The best solution would probably be that it automatically picks up changes and mirrors them on the server when I save a file.
I notice that RSYNC does pretty much what I need, I use a script for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look into using [RSYNC](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20031024013757927), which works with Macs, LInux, and even windows.  Great mirroring tool that replicates just changes..